# Count characters in a string (excluding spaces) in R?

Tags: r, string, character, gsub

I want to count the number of characters in a string (excluding spaces) and I'd like to know if my approach can be improved.

Suppose I have:

```
x <- "hello to you"
```

I know `nchar()` will give me the number of characters in a string (including spaces):

```
> nchar(x)
[1] 12
```

But I'd like to return the following (excluding spaces):

```
[1] 10
```

To this end, I've done the following:

```
> nchar(gsub(" ", "",x))
[1] 10
```

My worry is the `gsub()` will take a long time over many strings. Is this the correct way to approach this, or is there a type of nchar'esque function that will return the number of characters without counting spaces?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many strings are you converting? 100 million took about 30 seconds on my machine. I think your technique is pretty reasonable.

Comment: You could use `stringi::stri_count` and it might be faster

Comment: @nograpes, I've been playing around with learning the language and was considering doing a book chapter as a string. Nice to know my approach isn't all too hackish. Thanks for giving me a baseline.

Comment: @RichardScriven: Thanks, I hadn't seen that before so I'll gladly check it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Building on Richard's comment, "stringi" would be a great consideration here:

The approach could be to calculate the overall string length and subtract the number of spaces.

Compare the following.

```
library(stringi)
library(microbenchmark)

x <- "hello to you"
x
# [1] "hello to you"
fun1 <- function(x) stri_length(x) - stri_count_fixed(x, " ")
fun2 <- function(x) nchar(gsub(" ", "",x))
y <- paste(as.vector(replicate(1000000, x, TRUE)), collapse = "     ")

microbenchmark(fun1(x), fun2(x))
# Unit: microseconds
#     expr   min    lq     mean median      uq    max neval
#  fun1(x) 5.560 5.988  8.65163  7.270  8.1255 44.047   100
#  fun2(x) 9.408 9.837 12.84670 10.691 12.4020 57.732   100
microbenchmark(fun1(y), fun2(y), times = 10)
# Unit: milliseconds
#     expr        min         lq      mean     median         uq        max neval
#  fun1(y)   68.22904   68.50273   69.6419   68.63914   70.47284   75.17682    10
#  fun2(y) 2009.14710 2011.05178 2042.8123 2030.10502 2079.87224 2090.09142    10
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this explanation. Not only am I going to check out stringi but I'm curious to look into the microbenchmark package so I can answer these type of questions for myself. Thanks for "teaching me how to fish" rather than just "giving me the fish."

Comment: @ChuckD., No problem. One thing to consider with these types of questions when you are exploring things on your own is that generally, adding a `fixed` argument if one is available generally gives a speed boost.

Comment: @ChuckD., and now that you know about microbenchmark, you should be able to test my previous comment on your own :-)

Comment: I'm going to dig into it and give it a shot! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, `stringi` seems most appropriate here. Try this:

```
library(stringi)
x <- "hello to you"
stri_stats_latex(x)
```

Result:

```
CharsWord CharsCmdEnvir    CharsWhite         Words          Cmds        Envirs 
       10             0             2             3             0             0
```

If you need it in a variable, you can access the parameters via regular [i], e.g.:
`stri_stats_latex(x)[1]`